# ImportError: cannot import name 'Testcase' from 'unittest'

Tags: python, testing

I'm trying to import the unit test from a `__init__.py` file. Hence I'm getting the error

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Testcase' from 'unittest'
```

Clarify me if I'm wrong.

Comment: kindly consider adding more information e.g. your complete error in the question

Comment: Try "TestCase" instead of "Testcase".

Answer (score 1):

use :

```
from unittest import TestCase
```

or

```
unittest.TestCase
```

example:

```
import unittest
class TestFoo(unittest.TestCase):
   def a:
   return ()
```

issue was with the case sentivity

Answer (score -1):

I think just doing this => Import `unittest` will solve everything